# Why does Expo Bare Workflow Android Project automatically grant the File and Media Permission?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-permissions

**Problem:** I just updated my React-Native/Expo bare workflow project to Expo SDK 43 and am using the MediaLibrary expo package to save files. The problem is that I use `MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync` and it never asks the user to grant the `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE`. Upon further inspection, it looks like it automatically grants these permissions. How do I make it stop doing that?

**What I have tried:** I have made sure that my Android Manifest has both `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">`and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`. I have uninstalled the app from my device and reinstalled but still, the permissions are granted. At this point, I am lost on how to fix this because any similar issue I find online only shows a fix for managed workflow Expo projects.

Here are the versions of everything I am using:
Expo: 43.0.3,
Expo MediaLibrary: 13.0.3,
Pixel 3a running Android 12,
React-Native: 0.64.3

If more information is needed let me know.

Edit: I also tested it on a Samsung Device running Android version 9 and it is still automatically granting the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out if I load the app on my device by using `npx react-native run-android` it would automatically grant the permissions for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` without asking the user to grant the permission. If instead I went into my android folder for my project and built an APK using `./gradlew assembleRelease` (or debug) and sideload the APK onto my device it will ask the user to grant the needed permissions. Doing this also fixed an issue I was having that caused icons I'd imported from `@expo/vector-icons` to not be bundled with the release version of my app.